# HTML Scraping with HTMLReader Search for Table Row Content and Return href

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, xcode, web-scraping

using Objective-C HTMLReader for my first (simple, I think) HTML scraping task. But there's little documentation with it, and after a lot of experimentation, can't quite get what I need.

I'm scraping an old HTML page whose largest feature is one table with three columns and many rows. Here's a sample of the table with one row:

```
<table border="1" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="6" bordercolor="#000000" bgcolor="#999999" style="margin-top:50px;width:100%;">
<tr height=30>
<td bgcolor="#34003C" align="left" valign="middle" background="background.gif"><span class="cls_TableHeader">Bands</span></td>
<td bgcolor="#34003C" align="left" valign="middle" background="background.gif"><span class="cls_TableHeader">Style</span></td>
<td bgcolor="#34003C" align="left" valign="middle" background="background.gif"><span class="cls_TableHeader">Country</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="cls_tdDisco0" align="left" valign="middle">
<a href="artist.asp?id=9322"><strong>THE BEATLES</strong></a>
</td>
<td class="cls_tdDisco0" align="left" valign="middle">
<span class="cls_DiscoText">Rock</span></td>
<td class="cls_tdDisco0" align="left" valign="middle"><span class="cls_DiscoText">England</span></td>
</tr>
```

there are, of course, many rows.

**What I'm trying to accomplish:**
I need to search for the td that contains "THE BEATLES", and extract the href attached to it (of course, even when it's contained in the middle of a lot of other rows)

**What I've tried:**
I can get the table itself with

```
HTMLDocument *home = [HTMLDocument documentWithData:data contentTypeHeader:nil];    
HTMLElement *table = [home firstNodeMatchingSelector:@"TABLE"];
HTMLNode *theActualTable =[table childAtIndex:1];
```

but I can't really use the method "nodesMatchingSelector" to search rows since what I'm looking for isn't a selector. I've tried getting the rows (via children), but then I'm looking at iterating through each row's children of children until I drill to the  tag that contains THE BEATLES and then using that index to get the a  tag attached to that? It seems that there should be a much easier way to do this with HTMLReader. I feel like I'm missing something simple.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Here is some psuedo code that might work for you:

1. Use nodesMatchingSelector to get all the tr in the table
2. Then loop through all the tr and get the first td of each tr
3. Then use nodesMatchingSelector again to get the strong tag
4. Then use node.textContent to get the text content of the strong tag

https://github.com/nolanw/HTMLReader has an example in the readme that shows using the textContent method

feel free to post follow up questions as comments if any of this doesn't make sense

Comment: Thanks!  Yes, this is the kind of solution I was headed for - your flowchart does put it into focus - thank you. I read that example in the readme, but didn't think it was all too helpful since the example searches for a unique class selector, and returns its text value from that - but I have used textContext and that will be useful at the end of the iteration.

But I was holding out for *maybe* something that didn't involve loops and loops...? Am I being too hopeful?

Comment: If you can use psuedo selectors, then you only have to do one loop: `tr > td:first-child > a > strong` to get all the strong elements that have the name in it, and loop through all results and check the text content.  Here is a link to the page on psuedo classes: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes